# Cannot run servicestack bundler

Tags: servicestack

I was trying to upgrade our installation of servicestack.bundler to version 1.1.22 but the new version won't work on Windows. I tried to download the nuget package into a new solution in Visual Studio but get the same error.

The error we get is
    { [Error: Cannot find module './to-css-visitor.js'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }

When I look in the node_modules folder and then the subfolders for Less there is no to-css-visitor.js file there. I cannot see the file in the source code on GitHub either. The source seems to look for the file in this folder:

```
node_modules/less/lib/less
```

Should the file be installed separately or is it missing from the source? Is there a better version than 1.1.20 to get instead?

Comment: I've been bitten by the same issue. The missing file appears to have been introduced in commit 16d5bb7129719aba7ce688280a55c3b32ce4f192 which would seem to have occurred after the build for 1.1.22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.1.27 appears to have rectified the issue.